# Django cms - plugin manyToMany variable always empty

Tags: django, django-models, polymorphic-associations, django-cms

I wrote a simple plugin which display contact people, but I need to exclude some contact on certain pages. So I added a related model to my plugin which use an "structure_to_exclude" ManyToMany relationship. My issue, when I get this variable it's allways empty.

The cms_plugins.py

```
class VMContactContactPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    module = 'VM Contact Plugin'
    render_template = 'vm_contact/calendars/contacts_list.html'
    model = VMContactCalendarPluginModel
    name = _('VM Contact plugin')

    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        print 'Instance : {0}'.format(instance)
        inst = instance.structure_to_exclude.all()
        print 'Instance.all() result : {0}'.format(inst)
        structures = Structure.objects.exclude(contact=None).exclude(pk__in=instance.structure_to_exclude.all().values_list('id',flat=True))
        context.update({
            'structures': structures,
        })
        return context

plugin_pool.register_plugin(VMContactContactPlugin)
```

The related model

```
 class VMContactCalendarPluginModel(CMSPlugin):
     structure_to_exclude = models.ManyToManyField(
         Structure,
         verbose_name=_(u'Structures à exclure'),
     )
```

The Structure Models (Polymorphic !!)

```
class Structure(PolymorphicModel):
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, blank=True, null=True)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Contact, blank=True, null=True, related_name='%(class)s_members')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Castor')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True)
    categories = CategoryManyToManyField('aldryn_categories.Category',
                                         verbose_name=_('categories'),
                                         blank=True)
    calendars = models.ManyToManyField(Calendar, blank=True)
    has_pages = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    avatar = FilerFileField(null=True, blank=True,
                                 on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    classcss =  models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=CSS_CLASS, default='5')
    order = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['order']
```

Print results :

Instance : 93

Instance.all() result : []

Any idea ? I tried to retrieve the plugin instance with the ID (93) to be sure that was not an issue with instance var but it doesn't change anything... 
Regards, robin

Answer (score 2):

For every plugin you create, there's two versions once you publish.
The public and the draft versions. So its perfectly fine for the ids to change.

Because relationships vary from project to project, anytime your plugin has relationships, you need to explicitly tell the cms how to "copy over" these relationships when publishing the page.

Please adapt your plugin model to have the following method:

```
def copy_relations(self, oldinstance):
    self.structure_to_exclude = oldinstance.structure_to_exclude.all()
```

You can read more about plugin relations in our [docs](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.4.x/how_to/custom_plugins.html#for-many-to-many-or-foreign-key-relations-to-other-objects).